# How to add same text multiple times?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document and I have to add the same text between the 2 same header on 500 pages...

Is there something that exist to do that repetitive task?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Please post online a small example (OneDrive, Dropbox etc). Destroy your data if it's confidential.

Comment: Save a sample document with the problem in a cloud resource like OneDrive or DropBox and include a link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

### EDITED ANSWER:

Open search/replace

**Step 1:**

- Search for `Organization:`
- Replace with `[include my text HERE]^pOrganization:`

`^p` will introduce a new Paragraph (newline), equivalent of hitting `Enter`. You might need to add other newline characters, this depends on the formatting of your document.

The problem here is that your text will take the style of the title, so you'll need to do a

**Step 2:**

- Search for `[include my text HERE]`
- Replace with `[include my text HERE]`, and from the "more" tab, choose `Format --> Style ...`, and choose the style you use for normal text (probably: `Normal`)

[image]

Comment: in that example the I write house but the word document contains different sentence on each paragraph ^^'

Comment: So, give an example that is realistic. Better yet, save a sample document with the problem in a cloud resource like OneDrive or DropBox and include a link in your question.

Comment: @killua see my edit.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon AFAIK comments to answers arrive to the answer's author, but not to the OP: you should tag the OP